# Flagging an id when having similar columns different values in R

Tags: r, filter, flags

I need to flag an `id` when they have different `grade` values in the `grade` columns. Here how my sample dataset looks like

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(11,22,33,44,55),
                 grade.1 = c(3,4,5,6,7),
                 grade.2 = c(3,4,5,NA,7),
                 grade.3 = c(4,4,6,5,7),
                 grade.4 = c(NA,NA,NA, 5, 7 ))

df$Grade <- paste0(df$grade.1, df$grade.2, df$grade.3, df$grade.4)

> df
  id grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4 Grade
1 11       3       3       4      NA 334NA
2 22       4       4       4      NA 444NA
3 33       5       5       6      NA 556NA
4 44       6      NA       5       5 6NA55
5 55       7       7       7       7  7777
```

When an `id` has different grade values in `grade.1` `grade.2` `grade.3` and `grade.4`, that row needs to be flagged. Having `NA` in that column does not affect the flagging.

In other words, if the `Grade` column at the end has any differential numbers, that `id` needs to be flagged.

My desired output should look like this:

```
> df
  id grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4        flag
1 11       3       3       4      NA     flagged
2 22       4       4       4      NA Not_flagged
3 33       5       5       6      NA     flagged
4 44       6      NA       5       5     flagged
5 55       7       7       7       7 Not_flagged
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **base R** solution using `rle` omitting NA values.

```
df$flag <- apply(df[,2:5], 1, function(x) 
  ifelse(length(rle(x[!is.na(x)])$lengths)==1, "not_flagged", "flagged"))

df
  id grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4        flag
1 11       3       3       4      NA     flagged
2 22       4       4       4      NA not_flagged
3 33       5       5       6      NA     flagged
4 44       6      NA       5       5     flagged
5 55       7       7       7       7 not_flagged
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55), grade.1 = c(3, 4, 
5, 6, 7), grade.2 = c(3, 4, 5, NA, 7), grade.3 = c(4, 4, 6, 5, 
7), grade.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id = c(11,22,33,44,55),
                 grade.1 = c(3,4,5,6,7),
                 grade.2 = c(3,4,5,NA,7),
                 grade.3 = c(4,4,6,5,7),
                 grade.4 = c(NA,NA,NA, 5, 7 ))

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(length(unique(na.omit(c_across(2:5))))  == 1,
                        "not-flagged", "flagged")) %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>      id grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4 flag       
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1    11       3       3       4      NA flagged    
#> 2    22       4       4       4      NA not-flagged
#> 3    33       5       5       6      NA flagged    
#> 4    44       6      NA       5       5 flagged    
#> 5    55       7       7       7       7 not-flagged
```

---

Using `data.table::uniqueN`, that counts the number of unique elements in a vector (and that allows for `NA` removal):

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(flag = if_else(uniqueN(c_across(2:5), na.rm = T)  == 1,
                        "not-flagged", "flagged")) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: thanks for your solution!

Comment: You are welcome, @amisos55!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach.

```
df$flag <- c("not_flagged", "flagged")[
  apply(df[-1L], 1L, \(x) length( (ux <- unique(x))[!is.na(ux)] ) > 1L) + 1L
]
```

Output

```
> df
  id grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4        flag
1 11       3       3       4      NA     flagged
2 22       4       4       4      NA not_flagged
3 33       5       5       6      NA     flagged
4 44       6      NA       5       5     flagged
5 55       7       7       7       7 not_flagged
```

Comment: thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

`n_distinct` from `dyplr` is very helpful: Here a version using a combination of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(id, Grade),
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(n_distinct(value, na.rm = TRUE)==1, "Not flagged", "Flagged")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
```

```
     id Grade flag        grade.1 grade.2 grade.3 grade.4
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    11 334NA Flagged           3       3       4      NA
2    22 444NA Not flagged       4       4       4      NA
3    33 556NA Flagged           5       5       6      NA
4    44 6NA55 Flagged           6      NA       5       5
5    55 7777  Not flagged       7       7       7       7
```